# Помогите расставить знаки препинания! Нужно срочно

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, обращение

Правильно будет поставить запятую до и после или же только после?

*Ты действительно такой, Федор, каким я тебя знаю?*

Comment: Сима, поясните, пожалуйста, что имеется в виду при использовании имени Федор? Тогда и ответ может измениться.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно так:

*Ты действительно такой, **Федор**, каким я тебя знаю?*

Трудно представить контекст, в котором нет запятой перед "Федор". Это имя является обращением, которое выделяется с двух сторон запятыми, если стоит в середине предложения.

Обращение можно переставить практически в любую позицию:

*Ты, **Федор**, действительно такой, каким я тебя знаю?

**Федор**, ты действительно такой, каким я тебя знаю?

Ты действительно, **Федор**, такой, каким я тебя знаю?

Ты действительно такой, каким я тебя знаю, **Федор**?*

См.: [Обращения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=126) (справочник Розенталя).

Comment: Ужасная позиция для обращения, трудно представить, чтобы так кто-то сказал. Больше похоже на разговорный вариант без обращения: *Ты действительно такой ФЁдор, каким я тебя знаю?*

Comment: @oleedd  Я думал о возможности такой интерпретации. Тогда надо, чтобы автор вопроса пояснил, что имеется в виду под "Фёдор". А позиция для обращения не такая уж и ужасная – в разговорной речи можно услышать всё что угодно,  "ненормальный" порядок слов с нарушением всех законов синтаксиса.